# CSS - Horizontal Div Layout

Tags: html, css

So, if I have a nest like this:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Is it possible to use **pure** CSS to make a dynamic horizontal layout?
[image: Small Window Layout]

Basically, this screen can only fit 2 vertical contents

[image: Bigger Window Layout]

So, this screen can fit 3 vertical contents

The body **shows a horizontal scrollbar** at the fixed-bottom. There could be more contents off the screen. The **contents flow left, but will flow into a new column when vertical space is full.** The extras ***flow as the arrow shows***.

**Both screens *SHOULD NOT* show a vertical scrollbar.** So is it possible and how? I tried using `display: flex`, but it does not do the order effect above. Javascript would be my last resort.

Please see jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7z4s/10/ (Note that I wanted the .outer div the fill body and scrollbar it bottom)

Please, **Firefox and Chrome** must be supported!

Comment: using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: Yes, it's possible so long as you don't care about older browsers.

Comment: Are you allowed to add "hints" to tell the CSS when it's a new column?

Maybe this JSFiddle helps get to the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/scottcanoni/W7z4s/8/

Comment: @Scott This is something I wanted to make, except the scrollbar at the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/W7z4s/10/

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be achieved using :nth-child to clear the float and media queries eg @media screen and (max-height: 700px) to alter which element to clear based on the height.

Comment: i like your idea :D, but using media query would be a little bit restricted, sadly...

Comment: You'd only need to use it to change the number of divs per column, so you would only need a couple of break points. It would be a matter of working out how to make the content fill the height consistently.

Comment: Any way good luck and let us know how you get on, it's an interesting dilemma.

Comment: setting for different size screen? I consider it as a hack, you know Apple's Retina display, I don't want to update my webpage everything they release a bigger screen

Comment: I'm don't think I agree, nth-child (http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) and media queries (http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) have wide browser support. I find it unusual to use media queries with heights but it isn't too hacky.

Comment: Regarding break points, even with widths I tend to set an upper limit, would that not be an option? Or you could always pre-emptively set larger break points, wouldn't imagine it needing many more.

Comment: Kind of, just searching for answers. You see, if you want to hack it with `@media-query`, you have to do it with: column with 1 content, 2 content, 3, 4, and so on. If anyone has a larger screen then my media queries, they wouldn't get the effect.

Please see my jsfiddle if you need to refresh memories. I suggest that it is too restrictive.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, not just larger screen sizes either, zoom would break it too.

Comment: Will have another play with this one when I find a spare hour.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using display: flex, but it does
>   not do the order effect above.

Well It worked for me:

```
.outer {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/W7z4s/11/)**

NB: This currently doesn't work in Firefox because it still doesn't support the flex-wrap property, however according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) - this will be supported in version 28

### EDIT: ([Updated FIDDLE which includes support for Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/W7z4s/14/))

With `@supports` we can temporarily use the `-moz-colums-count` for Firefox as long as flex-wrap is not supported - sort of like Modernizr, but with CSS.

The good thing here, is that [Firefox supports them](http://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries).

So if I add the following code:

```
@supports (not (flex-wrap: wrap)) and (-moz-columns: 4) {
    .outer { 
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
        display: block;
        width:120%;
    }
}
```

Now, Firefox will use CSS columns, whereas other browsers will use flexbox.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I didn't even know there was a `@support` thing! I learn as I go. But using the `-moz-column` made it very restrictive. :(

Comment: According to caniuse, Firefox will support flex-wrap in it's next version anyway - so pretty soon you'll be able to use flexbox for all

Answer (score 0):

Now this is messy and I wouldn't recommend it, but it could sort of work. Using css transform we can rotate the containing div 90deg then rotate the child div back the other way.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>vertical rows - messy hack</title>
<style>
html, body, .wrapper {
    background-color: #666;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.wrapper {
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 5%;
    height: 90%;
    width:90%;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left:15px;
    top: 15px;
    height:;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
.container div {
    width:150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    float:right;
    margin: 20px;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what i did, please see my updated question for my fiddle. the scrollbar results on top for me

Comment: I haven't worked out scroll bar issues, just a way of making elements float to the top. Check the way the numbers flow. I'm off out now will check back later